# Tensorflow for poets 2: How to capture an image with a button rather than the application automatically capturing image?

Tags: android

I have read through the Android project found here: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2

The application takes images continuously which is not my preference on using it. What if I have placed a button on the view, and that button should trigger to capture an image?

I am not sure on how to prevent the application on taking images continuously. Does anyone have an idea? Help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.